# Play video in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, flash

I am trying to embed flash player on my web site. But for some reason the files are not playing. I am not able to see video player. Below is my code

```
_uri = Filepath + filename;  //--local Video

sb.Append("<object type='application/x-shockwave-flash' width='315px' height='230px' data='flvplayer_v5.6.swf?file=" + _uri + "&amp;autostart=false'>");
sb.Append("<param name='movie' value='flvplayer_v5.6.swf?file=" + _uri + "&amp;autostart=false'>");
sb.Append("<param name='allowfullscreen' value='true'><a href='http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer'></a></object>");
```

Any help on how to enable flash player to play .swf , .flv , .mov videos?

Edit : Below code for Youtube works fine

```
    _uri = filename;
sb.Append("<iframe frameborder='0' width='315px' height='230px' src='" + _uri + "' allowfullscreen>");
sb.Append("</iframe>");
sb.Append("<br /><a href='" + externalurl + "'  target='_blank'></a>");
                    dvMyHtml.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: what do you mean by _some reason the files are not playing_ ? did it gave some messages, anything strange happened ?

Comment: @coder No. No error, message. Code is compiling fine,but video is not played :(

Comment: can you show the full relevant code, so that we can have a look at it ?

Comment: @coder I have pasted all relevant code

Comment: so you mean to say, `youtube` videos are running and the videos related to `flash` are not playing. is that correct ?

Comment: so basically you need to enable flash, first check that `url` is working on other pc where flash is installed

Comment: flash has to installed on PC or browser that is running website?

Answer (score 1):

As discussed, the main issue seems to me is of `flash` which is stopping the videos to be played other than `youtube` videos.

So the first thing comes to me from [here](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Play-Flash-Video.aspx) is

> browser must have plug-in installed in order make this work.

As per documentation from [here](http://You%20can't%20show%20flash%20video%20files%20directly.%20Flash%20is%20just%20a%20programming%20framework,%20which%20uses%20Action%20Script%20programming%20language.%20You%20need%20a%20program%20made%20in%20Flash%20(video%20player)%20to%20show%20.flv%20video%20on%20page.) It states that

> You can't show flash video files directly. Flash is just a programming framework, which uses Action Script programming language. You need a program made in Flash (video player) to show .flv video on page.

So the basic code for that here is

```
<td align="left" valign="top">
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0"
        width="200" height="100">
        <param name="movie" value="<% =swfFileName%>" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <embed src="<% =swfFileName%>" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="200" height="100"></embed>
    </object>
</td>
```

For full reference find the link below:-

**http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30512/How-To-Play-SWF-File-In-Asp-Net**

**UPDATED** (*Code for playing .swf videos*)

It is very simple to create and to play *swf* file.

1. Open Microsoft Visual Studio. Create a web site and named it `PlaySwfFile`.
2. Create an .aspx file and named it `PlaySwfFile.aspx`.
3. Design the form that looks like this.

[image]

4. Or copy and paste the code in  `PlaySwfFile.aspx` file inside the `<body>` tag

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table width="410px">
            <tr>
                <td align="center"  valign="top">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3" style="width: 400px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" style="width: 150px">
                            </td>
                            <td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 200px">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" CssClass="tdMessage"  Text ="" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" class="tdText" align="left">
                              <nobr> Select a file</nobr> </td>
                            <td valign="top" style="text-align: left">
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="fUpload" runat="server" Width="300px" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" /></td>
                            <td align="left" valign="top">
                                <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0"
                                    width="200" height="100">
                                    <param name="movie" value="<% =swfFileName%>" />
                                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                                    <embed src="<% =swfFileName%>" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
                                        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="200" height="100"></embed>
                                </object>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

5. Now Add a namespace `System.IO;` to the   `PlaySwfFile.aspx.cs` file
6. Declare a variable above page_load() method

   ```
   public string swfFileName = "";
   ```
7. And the code for `Upload button` is below

Button code:-

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fUpload.FileContent.Length > 0 && IsVaildFile())
    {
        string Path = GetUplaodImagePhysicalPath();
        DirectoryInfo dirUploadImage = new DirectoryInfo(Path);
        if (dirUploadImage.Exists == false)
        {
            dirUploadImage.Create();
        }
        string fileUrl = Path + fUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
        fUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(fileUrl);
        swfFileName = "image/" + fUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
    }
}
```

Checking whether uploaded file is `swf` or not

```
private bool IsVaildFile()
{
    string swfExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
    switch (swfExt)
    {
        case ".swf":
            return true;
        default:
            {
                lblMsg.Text = "Please select only swf file.";
                return false;
            }
    }
}
string GetUplaodImagePhysicalPath()
{
    return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "image\\";
}
```

This is the full code for uploading flash videos and playing it on the browser.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. None of link are owrking. can you please check it

Comment: which link you are talking about ? did you installed the flash plugin in browser ?

Comment: The above link that you gave in answer

Comment: The link is working, I gave the above code from their only.will check it again. Which flash player are you talking about ? Give me sometime I will create a scenario and check whether it works on my end or not

Comment: @Richa; See the updated answer, this should work for you now.

Comment: Yes. .swf files are playing but not .mov and .flv :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99771/discussion-between-coder-and-richa).